# Insert a text into a textbox and simulate click on the button in Bot Framework's Web Chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/chpaeeL9/1/

Microsoft Bot Framework has a webchat module that allows you to talk to your bot.

When the user clicks the `Say Hi` button, I want to place some text into the webchat's textbox, and click the Send button inside the webchat using JavaScript.

Sounds like something too easy, but it wasn't. Here's the code that I currently have, and it doesn't work: the click event somehow is not triggered.

```
$('#sayhibutton').click(function() {
  $('.wc-console').addClass('has-text'); // works
  $('.wc-shellinput').val("Hi bot!").change(); // works
  $('.wc-send').click(); // doesn't work!
  $('.wc-send svg').click(); // doesn't work either
});
```

Update: if that helps, it seems the interface is written using React.

Update: my question is different from my previous question about how to avoid iframes in webchat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically send a message into the WebChat window in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895279/automatically-send-a-message-into-the-webchat-window-in-bot-framework)

Answer (score 3):

OK, for the lack of a better option my solution was a pretty dirty and ugly one.

Save the code in `botchat.js` into a file and reference that saved file from the HTML, rather than the CDN version.

Pretty-print the file in Chrome and find the line that says:

```
e.prototype.sendMessage = function() {
  this.props.inputText.trim().length > 0 && this.props.sendMessage(this.props.inputText)
}
```

Replace the middle line with this:

```
this.textInput.value.trim().length > 0 && this.props.sendMessage(this.textInput.value)
```

This basically means to take the message text from `this.textInput.value` rather than from `this.props.inputText`, or in other words, take it directly from the textinput's DOM node.

Somehow triggering the `change` event on a textbox doesn't cause an actual `change` event on the textbox, which is why we need to do this.

Comment: seems a bit out of scope. as you would really just use directline.  and then compose a message, or alternative is to use the backchannel,  that is specifically built for this scenario

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat   link to there repo, and info on direct line and info on backchannel

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with react try this,

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-shellinput")[0];
        var lastValue = input.value;
        input.value = 'YOUR MESSAGE';
        var event = new CustomEvent('input', { bubbles: true });
        // hack React15
        event.simulated = true;
        // hack React16
        var tracker = input._valueTracker;
        if (tracker) {
            tracker.setValue(lastValue);
        }
        input.dispatchEvent(event);

        //send the message 
        $(".wc-send:first").click();
```

to read more see this post: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/680