# How to inject text in to React component of Microsoft botframework-webchat ?

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I want to add and send a message in Microsoft chatbot without typing that message on textArea which is at the bottom of the Bot window. 
I need to give the message as a props to the react component (botframework-webchat).

I tried suggestions given in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903162/insert-a-text-into-a-textbox-and-simulate-click-on-the-button-in-bot-frameworks?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and it does not work for me.

How can I do that?

I tried this.

```
import { Chat } from "botframework-webchat";

class ChatBox extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
   document.getElementsByClassName('wc-shellinput')[0].value = "testMsg"
   document.getElementsByClassName('wc-send')[0].click()
}

render() {
   return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
         <Chat
            directLine={{
               secret:
               "...."
            }}
            user={{ id: "Test" }}
            bot={{ id: "Demo" }}
            resize={"detect"}
            ref="chatBox"
         />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in React, but I found that in React, we only can update the input value via its state. And via [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Shell.tsx#L16), it seems that there is an entrance function called `onChangeText()`.

So, please try following code snippet to update the input value:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.chat);
    this.chat.shellRef.props.onChangeText('testMsg');      
  }
```

Comment: I added that to my code  as `this.refs.chatBox.shellRef.props.onChangeText('testMsg')` and it worked.. You save my day. **Thank you so much...**